# C# mongodbdriver increase performance of join collection

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-query

I have a following linq statement for join operation on two collections;

```cs
var combinedVaersIdListQuery = vaersDataCollection
    .AsQueryable()
    .Join(
        vaersVaxCollection.AsQueryable(),
        a => a.VAERS_ID,
        b => b.VAERS_ID,
        (a, b) => new { a, b }
    )
    .Where(x =>
        allFilters.vaersVaxFilter.VAXMANUFACTURERLIST.Contains(x.b.VAX_MANU) &&
        allFilters.vaersVaxFilter.VAXNAMESLIST.Contains(x.b.VAX_NAME) &&
        allFilters.vaersVaxFilter.VAXTYPESLIST.Contains(x.b.VAX_TYPE) &&
        allFilters.sexFilters.Contains(x.a.SEX) &&
        recvDateList.Contains(x.a.VAERS_ID)
    );
```

And this is the query and other info which got from mongoDB profiler from MongoDBCompass;

```
{
  "type": "op",
  "host": "CANYILDIRMAZ:27017",
  "desc": "conn147",
  "connectionId": 147,
  "client": "127.0.0.1:63466",
  "appName": "MongoDB Compass",
  "clientMetadata": {
    "application": {
      "name": "MongoDB Compass"
    },
    "driver": {
      "name": "mongo-csharp-driver|legacy",
      "version": "2.15.0.0"
    },
    "os": {
      "type": "Windows",
      "name": "Microsoft Windows 10.0.17763",
      "architecture": "x86_64",
      "version": "10.0.17763"
    },
    "platform": ".NET 6.0.1"
  },
  "active": "true",
  "currentOpTime": "2022-05-03T16:55:33.155+03:00",
  "threaded": true,
  "opid": 1584537,
  "lsid": {
    "id": "j2PKkNAySDGyqBhmtCSpgg==",
    "uid": "47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU="
  },
  "secs_running": 22,
  "microsecs_running": 22608998,
  "op": "command",
  "ns": "MyExperimentalDB.VaersData",
  "command": {
    "aggregate": "VaersData",
    "pipeline": [{
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "VaersVax",
          "localField": "VAERS_ID",
          "foreignField": "VAERS_ID",
          "as": "b"
        }
      },
      {
        "$unwind": "$b"
      },
      {
        "$match": {
          "b.VAX_MANU": {
            "$in": [
              "PFIZER\\BIONTECH"
            ]
          },
          "b.VAX_NAME": {
            "$in": [
              "COVID19 (COVID19 (PFIZER-BIONTECH))"
            ]
          },
          "b.VAX_TYPE": {
            "$in": [
              "COVID19"
            ]
          },
          "SEX": {
            "$in": [
              "F"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "VAERS_ID": "$VAERS_ID",
          "_id": 0
        }
      }
    ],
    "cursor": {},
    "$db": "MyExperimentalDB",
    "lsid": {
      "id": "j2PKkNAySDGyqBhmtCSpgg=="
    }
  },
  "planSummary": "IXSCAN { SEX: -1 }",
  "numYields": 255,
  "locks": {
    "Global": "r"
  },
  "waitingForLock": "false",
  "lockStats": {
    "Global": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 273069
      }
    },
    "Mutex": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 272814
      }
    }
  },
  "waitingForFlowControl": false,
  "flowControlStats": {}
```

This query is taking almost 100 seconds. Query is using index. Is my approach ok or is there any better option(a better linq or maybe join two IQueryables which where conditions specified from beginning) that increase performace of this query?

Comment: What is the size of your data? Also recheck that all index exists on mongo.

Comment: @LeBigCat The collection related with join operation has data between 1.300.000 and 1.700.000. I checked indexes and usages from MongoDBCompass and i see that index is there and using. By the way the data is not changing, i am only reading data and doing calculations.

Comment: Joins is just a map reduice (client side, note i not use the last version, but i didnot read any change about it) so he will load all the data client side.
Take a loot to aggregation, it could reduice the amount of data  (according to your context) (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem like this;

```
List<string> filteredVaersDataCollection = await vaersDataCollection.AsQueryable().Where(x => allFilters.sexFilters.Contains(x.SEX) &&
recvDateList.Contains(x.VAERS_ID)).Select(x => x.VAERS_ID).ToListAsync();

List<string> filteredVaersVaxCollection = await vaersVaxCollection.AsQueryable().Where(x => allFilters.vaersVaxFilter.VAXMANUFACTURERLIST.Contains(x.VAX_MANU) &&                                allFilters.vaersVaxFilter.VAXNAMESLIST.Contains(x.VAX_NAME) &&                              allFilters.vaersVaxFilter.VAXTYPESLIST.Contains(x.VAX_TYPE)).Select(x => x.VAERS_ID).ToListAsync();

vaersIdList = filteredVaersDataCollection.Intersect(filteredVaersVaxCollection).ToHashSet();
```

I tried to use Aggregate and LookUp but it required to use BsonDocument for Match operation, i need to use LINQ approach to use my model classes. Hence, i split up the query on two pieces, i get ids and intersected them to get inner join result as same.

With that approach i also gained performance. I decreased time 10-15 seconds.

Thank you for all support.